# Jinja globals in django - using coffin

Tags: django, global-variables, jinja2

I have some helper functions I want to access from my templates, but having trouble accessing these.
Using Jinja2 with Coffin (which is great, except I can't seem to access my global functions).

I register my objects in jinja.py

```
from coffin.template import Library
register = Library()

@register.object(name='tester')
def tester():
    return 'TESTING YAA!!'

print (register.jinja2_globals)
```

My template tester.html looks like this:

```
{{  tester() }}
```

But this is what happens:

```
>>> from apps import jinja
{'tester': <function tester at 0x3133938>}
>>> jinja.tester()
'TESTING YAA!!'
```

Import works fine and the function registers correctly but can't access with render_to_response or render_to_string:

```
>>> from coffin.template.loader import render_to_string as rts
>>> rts('tester.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/pydev/drew/iame/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Coffin-0.3.7.dev-py2.6.egg/coffin/template/loader.py", line 55, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context_instance)
  File "/pydev/drew/iame/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Coffin-0.3.7.dev-py2.6.egg/coffin/template/__init__.py", line 56, in render
    return super(Template, self).render(**context)
  File "/pydev/drew/iame/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/pydev/drew/iame/iame_cms/apps/templates/tester.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {{  tester() }}
UndefinedError: 'tester' is undefined
```

But isn't accessible in my template :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your library to be loaded, it must be in a standard location, namely where Django expects such libraries:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

i.e., something like `my_app/templatetags/customlib.py`.

Comment: Amazing, but this also applies when using coffin. Prior to doing this my globals were being loaded, but they were not accessible from templates.

Comment: Tested and all fine now. THANKS SOO MUCH :D